# Understanding translation between R and rpy2

Tags: r, rpy2

The documentation for `rpy2` is confusing me. In `R`, one would use the `help()` interface to find our how certain things in `R` actually work. For example, `help(print)` shows how to use `print()`; it gives a description, the usage, and examples, e.g.

```
‘print’ prints its argument and returns it _invisibly_ (via
 ‘invisible(x)’).  It is a generic function which means that new
 printing methods can be easily added for new ‘class’es.
```

Is there a simple way to find out how to execute each method from `R` in `rpy2` using `rpy2`? To get help using `rpy2`, one would use

```
>>> from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
>>> utils = importr("utils")
>>> help_doc = utils.help("print")
```

and then convert the object to a string to see the documentation, i.e. `str(help_doc)`. However, this only prints the documentation from `R`, it doesn't show me how to implement `print` in `rpy2`.

Is there better way to quickly translate between `R` and `rpy2`?

Example: loading data files, `file.Rdata`

In `R`, one would use the function `load()`, i.e.

```
 source("file.Rdata")
```

and the data file is uploaded.

In `rpy2`, one would use the `load()` function and convert to Python objects as appropriate, i.e

```
>>> import rpy2.robjects as robjects
>>> robjects.r['load']("file.RData")
```

Then, in order to manipulate these objects in `numpy`, one would simply use

```
from rpy2.robjects import numpy2ri
```

and convert `R` vectors/arrays into `numpy` arrays using `numpy.asarray()` or `numpy.array()`.

http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.6/html/numpy.html

Comment: The link is for the doc of an old release of rpy2. Consider changing 2.2 to 2.6 in the URL.

Comment: @lgautier You're right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`rpy2` is providing different ways to access R data structures or functions.

With `importr()` you have a number of convenience functionalities. One of which is a dynamic generation of Python docstrings from the R man pages.

For example, try in ipython:

```
In [1]: from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

In [2]: base = importr("base")

In [3]: ?base.print
```

For `rpy2` specific data structures and function, there is documentation (the link in the question). Not perfect, but improving over time thanks for contributions and feedback.